# count and order in sql at ms-access

Tags: sql, ms-access, count

I have a table (called Tweets) in ms-access that looks like this

```
text    screenName
lala      user1
la        user2
lal       user3
lalala    user1
l         user1
a         user4
```

I would like to have in the end a table, that will contain the number of `text` per user. The column with the number of `text`, I would like to have a certain name for it (e.g. `newColumn`) and also the table to be sorted first by the number of texts (`newColumn`) (descending) and then by the `screenName` (ascending).

So far I have

```
SELECT COUNT(text), screenName
FROM Tweets
GROUP BY screenName;
```

But I don't know how to sort and to rename the new column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
select COUNT(text) as num_of_texts,
    screenName
from Tweets
group by screenName
order by COUNT(text) desc, screenName;
```

Comment: can i put 2 order by ? so
`select COUNT(text) as num_of_texts,
    screenName
from Tweets
group by screenName
order by num_of_texts desc
order by screenName asc;` ?

Comment: when I run the query i get a pop up box that asks me to fill in the num_of_texts.

Comment: @quant - Apparently access doesn't allow alias to be used in the order. Updated the answer. Please try now.

Comment: It worked ! Thank you a lot ! Any ideas why access does not accept alias ? I am using ms-access 2016

Comment: @quant - It's probably working how it's programmed to work. Access has a very limited functionality.